# Unix script to read the file and create a file for each line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file and my task is to read the file and generate a new file for each line. The name of newly generated file should come from the line content.

Example

The file has these two lines:

```
My name is hello world
My Name is not hello world
```

> What I want is the following: File 1 should have 1 record and name of
>   this file is fourth field of row which

What do you mean exactly?

First file should be named:

```
hello
```

> File 2 should have 2nd record and name of the file should be 4 field of row which is not.

Here also. What do you mean exactly?

Second file should be named:

```
not
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post on this site. To get to your question, what have you tried so far? You mention that you are using a UNIX system, could you include what shell or operating system you are using to help others know what tools you have available? [Please edit your post to include this information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/475148/edit). The more context you can add the better others will be able to help you!

Comment: Hello @Animesh Saxena  would you please check the answer below and let me know if this is what you need? Please re-edit the question for further clarifications and include the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @Animesh, Is this what you want?  `awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if(i == 4) print $0 > $i}' main`   where `main` is the name of your file.

Comment: @valentine this is not giving output

Comment: @AnimeshSaxena It will create 2 files.  Once again `main` is your filename containing those 2 lines

Answer (score 2):

```
$cat mainfile
My name is hello world
My Name is not hello world
```

In `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
cat mainfile | while IFS= read line ;do 

name=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $4}')

echo "${line}" >> ${name} 
done
```

In `csh`

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach line ( "`cat mainfile`" )
set name = `echo ${line} | awk '{print $4}'`

    echo "${line}" >> $name
end
```

In order to create files for all the words in the mainfile

```
#!/bin/bash
cat mainfile | while IFS= read line ;do

     for word in $line; do

   echo "${line}" >> ${word} 
  done
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this it really helps. I used cut -d ‘,’ -f4 in place of awk I hope that should be okay. Second when I execute this with 4 lines in main file I am getting 3 rows in 1 file and 4 row in 1 file, please tell me if there is an issue

Comment: But there is an issue as I need 4 files if there are 4 rows in main file. Please help me on this

Comment: Are you using bash? for first file you need file named (My) (name) (is) (hello) (world) ? these are five not four please confirm?

Comment: Yes I am using bash. For first file I need the whole row in new file and the name of the new file will be the fourth world of row which is hello and identifier as .txt

Comment: @AnimeshSaxena please see my edits and let me know if this is what you need ;-)

Comment: I am thankful for your patience and help. Everything is what I need but when I execute for my requirement with 4 rows in my main file, I am expecting 4 file with 4th word as name of file. But I am getting 2 files only where 4th row is coming as 1 file and too 3 rows coming in other file. Please help me. I am available at Email itisanimesh@gmail.com

Comment: @Animesh Saxena. Do you want file for every word in the file?

Comment: Why do you touch then append? Why don't you just use the `echo "$var" > "$file"` which does CREAT and TRUNC?

Comment: @glenn jackman thank you so much!  I really don't know why I did that! Supper funny ;-)))

Comment: No I don’t need file for each word. I need a file for each line but the name of the file is a word from the line. Example line is my name is hello world. So this is one file and file name is hello as it is fourth word of line

Comment: @Animesh Saxena which word? not and hello correct. The code above can do it? what is the problem?

Comment: Yes not and hello those are the words. So when I execute this code with 4 rows in main file. It is creating only 2 files not four but names are coming correct. I can share screenshots if you mail me at itisanimesh@gmail.com. Thank you

Comment: @Animesh Saxena probably the fourth word in the third and fourth lines in the file are the same?

Comment: Bang on you are absolutely correct they are same, is that an issue

Comment: Of course they will be saved as a one file if both both lines (forth words) are the same. You can't just name the files based on the fourth word. This is risky, you need an additional criteria for naming files. For example, the fourth word and something else like an arbitrary number. Let me know what works best for you then I will tweak the commands for you.

Answer (score 1):

The lines of the file should be written to files whose names are taken from the fourth whitespace-delimited field. The word "record" refers to the a line.  The word "column" is sometimes used in place for "field", and here one could have used the word "word" instead of "field".  Both "record" and "field" are more generic than "line" and "column" (or "word").  In particular, a line is a newline-delimited record, and a "field" is often a whitespace-delimited column or word inside a record.

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ print >$4 }' <file.txt
```

This would run the `print` statement once for each line in the input file `file.txt`.  The `>$4` means that the output is redirected to a file named by the fourth field in the line.  For the first line, this creates the file `hello` and for the second line, this creates the file `not`.

```
$ cat hello
My name is hello world
```

```
$ cat not
My Name is not hello world
```

If further lines were present in the file, each line would have been written to the files given by its fourth word. If two lines has the *same* fourth word, both lines would be written to the same file.

If a line has less than four words, this would generate an error.

`awk` uses newlines as the default record separator, and whitespace (tabs or spaces) as field delimiters, unless told otherwise.

---

Advanced `awk`-ness:

When doing this sort of redirection within an `awk` program, `awk` will keep the files opened until it exits, after reading all the data.  Each open file requires one filedescriptor, and there's a limited number of these.  If *many* files have to be written to, it's a good idea to close the files explicitly:

```
awk '{ print >>$4; close($4) }' <file.txt
```

Here, we open the output for appending to (rather than truncating and overwriting), write the current line to the file and close the file. When the same file is opened for output a second time (because field four happens to be the same for two or more lines), the data is appended.  Had we used `>$4`, the new data would have overwritten the old.  This is not a problem in the first program at the top as we never explicitly close the files.

The script (or whatever calls the `awk` program) would have to arrange for the output files to be empty or non-existing before running this, depending on circumstances.

Removing the files `hello` and `not`, and running the above command thrice:

```
$ rm hello not
$ awk '{ print >>$4; close($4) }' <file.txt
$ awk '{ print >>$4; close($4) }' <file.txt
$ awk '{ print >>$4; close($4) }' <file.txt
```

```
$ cat hello
My name is hello world
My name is hello world
My name is hello world
```

```
$ cat not
My Name is not hello world
My Name is not hello world
My Name is not hello world
```